# Inner product of vector spaces property proof: $\langle A^tA v, v\rangle = \langle\lambda ^2 v, v\rangle$?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

$\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$As a homework assignment we had to show that if $\lambda$ is eigenvalue for the matrix $A$, then it is an eigenvalue for $A^t$.

To prove this, I followed this idea:
$$
\Brak{AA^t v, v}
  = \Brak{A v, A v}
  = \Brak{\lambda v, \lambda v}
  = \lambda^2 \Brak{v, v}
  = \Brak{\lambda^2 v, v}.
$$
But my professor told me that my way of showing it is inconsistent, namely I need a proof for $\Brak{A^tA v, v} = \Brak{\lambda^2 v, v}$.

Could anyone point out any way to prove this?

Comment: I would instead look at the determinants of $A-\lambda v$ and $A^t-\lambda v$.

Comment: How does $\langle AA^t v, v\rangle = \langle \lambda^2 v, v\rangle $ implies that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^t$?

Comment: @theSongbird: I took the liberty of tweaking the math. (Less-than and greater-than signs space like operators; the delimiters `\langle` and `\rangle` are your friends here. :) Separately, are you sure the question didn't ask about $\Brak{A^{t}Av, v}$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang My bad, sir! Thank you for poinint out the mistake :)

Comment: Your proof is formally correct if the matrix product should have read $A^{t}A$ rather than $AA^{t}$; just remove the transposes after the first equals sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $\det(A) = \det(A^t)$, moreover $(A + \lambda I)^t = (A^t + \lambda I)$, therefore

$$
\det(A + \lambda I) = \det(A+\lambda I)^t = \det(A^t+\lambda I)
$$

So, if $\lambda$ is a solution of $\det(A + \lambda I) = 0$, it is also a solution of $\det(A^t+\lambda I)$. Rewording, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then it is also an eigenvalue of $A^t$

Comment: Cool thing, bro, but do you have any idea as how to prove $\Brak{A^tA v, v} = \Brak{\lambda^2 v, v}$?