# Prove that $\langle AA^t v, v\rangle = \langle A^t v, A^t v\rangle $

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Can someone help me prove that $\langle AA^t v, v\rangle  = \langle A^t v, A^t v\rangle $? Thanks a lot!

PS: I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290248/inner-product-of-vector-spaces-property-proof-langle-ata-v-v-rangle-lang) fairly similar to this one before, but it in it I proved something using the above result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vectors $x$ and $y$ and a matrix $A$, we have
$$
\langle Ax,y\rangle=(Ax)^ty=(x^tA^t)y=x^t(A^ty)=\langle x,A^ty\rangle
$$
Now set $x=A^tv$ an $y=v$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that the inner product is defined by $\langle u,v\rangle = u^t v$, one has
$$\langle AA^t v,v\rangle=(AA^tv)^t v=v^t(A^t)^tA^t v=(A^tv)^t(A^tv)=\langle A^tv,A^tv \rangle. $$